# Background Worker's ReportProgress for an Asynchronous task

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, backgroundworker

I am using a `BackgroundWorker` to send asynchronous HTTP requests (with RestSharp by the way) and need to pass the returned data (HTTP response) to the main thread to update some GUI components based on that data. For this I use `ReportProgress` method like this:

```
static void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    Object[] args = (Object[])e.Argument;

    string strURL = args[0].ToString();
    string strParam = args[1].ToString();

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {

        var client = new RestClient(strURL);
        var request = new RestRequest(strURL, Method.POST);

        request.AddParameter("someparam", strParam);        

        client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
        {
            string strRet = response.Content;
            worker.ReportProgress(i, strArr);
        } 

    }

}
```

This code will raise an exception on `ReporProgress` saying that it is illegal to call this method when the `Background Worker` has already finished its work and it is absolutely correct because by the time I receive HTTP response the `bw_DoWork` will already have finished executing. 
So as you can see I am dealing with an asynchronous task in already asynchronous Background Worker thread. 
I know that `ReportProgress` is marshaled to execute on GUI thread and I don't see any other ways to pass data back to the main form. How can this be fixed/corrected?

Comment: Not the main point but if you would get it to work this way you would see 5 reports for `i==5` due to capturing.

Comment: The Backgroundworker has no function (other tah ReportProgress) here so drop it. Use aync/await instead.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes that's the point, it's supposed to execute multiple times. Otherwise I would use RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler to pass the data

Comment: @HenkHolterman Actually never mind, RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler would raise the same exception

Comment: What I meant is that your progress values won't be 0,1,2,3,4 but 5,5,5,5,5.

Comment: Ah yes, this is just an example code though

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to let your background worker sleep/wait until all ExecuteAsync´s are finished.
You can do it like this.

```cs
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    Object[] args = (Object[])e.Argument;

    string strURL = args[0].ToString();
    string strParam = args[1].ToString();

    int finishedCounter = 0;

    // A reset event that is set from the last ExecuteAsync
    AutoResetEvent finishedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {     

        var client = new RestClient(strURL);
        var request = new RestRequest(strURL, Method.POST);

        request.AddParameter("someparam", strParam); 

        client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
        {
            string strRet = response.Content;
            worker.ReportProgress(i, strArr);

            // Check if this is the last worker/step then
            // wake up the background worker to finish the do_work method
            if (Interlocked.Increment(ref finishedCounter) == 5) 
                finishedEvent.Set();    
        });
    }

    // wait till work is done
    finishedEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

An alternative would be to not use a BackgroundWorker at all. 
You can update the UI in WPF using the MainWindow´s dispatcher.

```cs
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        // Update UI
    });

or 

System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        // Update UI
    });
```

Or in Windows Forms using a concrete Form

```cs
System.Windows.Forms.Form form = ...;

form.Invoke(new Action( () =>
    {
        //Update UI
    }));
```